# How do you make a running sum for fizz buzz in python?

Tags: python, cumulative-sum, fizzbuzz

So i am trying to make the fizz buzz program in python but that keeps a running sum of the numbers of fizz and buzz. so far i have this:

```
for number in range(100):
    number += 1
    if number % 5 == 0 and number % 3 == 0:
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        print('buzz')
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        print('fizz')
    else:
        print(number)
```

Comment: What do you mean "numbers of fizz and buzz"? You can create a variable to keep track of the running sum, and add `number` whenever you want to.

Comment: Just remove this line:
number +=1 and you are good to go. Also store sum in a variable.
sum_fizz_buzz = 0
and increase this variable each time 5 or 3 condition is met.

Comment: and will add up the numbers that got replaced with fizz/buzz?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `sumFizzBuzz` variable and accumulate to it as needed:

```py
sumFizzBuzz = 0
for number in range(100):
    if number % 5 == 0 and number % 3 == 0:
        # Not sure if according to the requirements you sum fizzbuzz numbers too
        print('fizzbuzz')
    elif number % 5 == 0:
        sumFizzBuzz += number
        print('buzz')
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        sumFizzBuzz += number
        print('fizz')
    else:
        print(number)
```